# css Horizontally center div in a div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to horizontally center a  block element on a page.

Here is an example of what I want:

[image]

I cannot use div hard sizing because layout should be responsive.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/rdy9nmp0/

Here is the code:

```
 <div class = "container">
    <div class="sub">
        <h1> 01</h1>
        <div class = "icon"><img src="img/settings.png" alt="">
            <h2> Power Inside</h2>
            <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montesmus. Pro vel nibh et elit mollis commodo et nec augueique</p>
            <a class="iconlink" href="/">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div>
```

CSS

```
.container {

    width: 1160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

.sub{
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; 
}

.sub h1{
    font-size: 90px;
    color: #efeff0;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    float:left;
}

.sub img
{
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.sub h2  {
    color: #2a2b2e;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.sub p {
    color: #8a8a8a;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
.sub .icon{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left:20px;
}
.sub .iconlink{
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #2a2b2e;
    height: 28px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    background: url(../img/shape_blue.png) no-repeat scroll right center #fff;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    background-position: right;
}

.container .iconlink:hover, .iconlink:hover {
    color: #248cec;
    background: url(../img/shape_grey.png) no-repeat scroll right center #fff; 
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background-position: right;
}
.container .iconlink a:active {
    color: #248cec;
}

img {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get what you want.

```
.container {
    display: flex; /*rather than inline-flex*/
}
```

If you do need `inline-flex` than make the parent element `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 0):

You can still have a responsive layout with "hard" sizing. You can use something called a media query at the bottom of your CSS file that when the page reaches a certain size it will adjust elements to what you have specified. Here is some example code:

```
     @media (max-width: 400px) {
       div {
         width: 20px;
        }
      }
```

Let me know if this makes sense or if you need more explanation. It can be a little confusing at first, but once you get it and see it in action it is pretty cut and dry.

Answer (score 0):

Just do wrapper div with width:100%, inside that div create another div with your desired total width and margin: 0 auto and inside that one create 3 divs with 33% width and float:left

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="subcont">
           <div><p>This is div1</p></div>
           <div><p>This is div2</p></div>
           <div><p>This is div3</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>

div:not(.container):not(.subcont){
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.subcont{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cbmkg2e5/